# Does nginx upstream server compress response data before it sends back to midstream server?

Tags: nginx, gzip

Here is my situation, browsers send http requests to my reverse proxy nginx server, my reverse proxy nginx server then ask upstream server for response, I was wondering whether upstream server will check if request header has "Accept-Encoding:gzip" and compress response data or just send raw data back to my reverse proxy nginx server?

Because when I use tcpdump to capture http response from upstream server to my nginx server,
I could see so much raw data there.

Comment: Does upstream server support gzip? In my experience upstreams don't bother to gzip response, they leave it to nginx.

Comment: Upstream server does support gzip, I found out that I incorrectly configured my reverse proxy server, I left out "proxy_http_version 1.1" in nginx.conf. After adding this to my nginx.conf, I could see gziped data instead of raw data in the http response sent back from upstream server.